# Can I do online / incremental learning on a loaded model using python sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I want to perform tag:incremental learning using the model sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveRegressor in python jupyter notebook for my Machine Learning project.

First time when I train the model using a dataset d1, I will do like this:

```
model_cpu = PassiveAggressiveRegressor(n_iter_no_change=100, epsilon=0.000001) #Initialize the model
model_cpu.partial_fit(X_train.values, y_cpu_train) #Train the model
joblib.dump(model_cpu, "Weights/"+folder_name+"/model_cpu_weights.pkl") #Save the model
```

Then I will close the jupyter notebook.

Next time when I train the model using a dataset d2 (d2 has the same attributes of d1, but its values are disjoint from that of d1), I will do like this:

```
model_cpu = joblib.load("Weights/"+folder_name+"/model_cpu_weights.pkl") #Load the saved model
model_cpu.partial_fit(X_train.values, y_cpu_train) #Perform incremental learning
joblib.dump(model_cpu, "Weights/"+folder_name+"/model_cpu_weights.pkl") #Save the model
```

Then I will close the jupyter notebook. I should repeat the process continuously. Is this possible? If not suggest a method to do so. Thanks in advance!

I am not sure whether my approach works. As sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveRegressor gives different predictions every time I train for the same dataset, there is no way for me to check if the incremental learning is actually working.

Comment: You can pass `random_state=42` to make the training of the model reproducible. Note, that `42` can be replaced by an arbitrary integer.